# z3 giving a surprising answer

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I tried this:

```
import z3
n,x,y,z = z3.Ints('n x y z')
s = z3.Solver()
s.add(4/n==1/x+1/y+1/z)
s.add(x>0)
s.add(n>0)
s.add(y>0)
s.add(z>0)
s.check()
s.model()
```

and I get:

```
[x = 1, n = 2, z = 3, y = 1, div0 = [(1, 1) → 1, (4, 2) → 2, else → 0], mod0 = [(1, 3) → 1, else → 0]]
```

But 4/2  does not equal 1/1+1/1+1/3.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared `n, x, y, z` as integers. So division is done as an integer, giving you `1/1 = 1` and `1/3 = 0`; hence satisfying the equality `2=2`.

The obvious thing to do is to use `Real` values for this problem.
Changing the declaration to:

```py
n,x,y,z = z3.Reals('n x y z')
```

produces:

```
[z = 1, y = 1, n = 4/3, x = 1]
```

which does satisfy the equation you posed trivially.

In case you actually do want `n, x, y, z` to be integers; then you should convert them to reals before you divide, like this:

```py
import z3
n,x,y,z = z3.Ints('n x y z')
s = z3.Solver()
s.add(4/z3.ToReal(n)==1/z3.ToReal(x)+1/z3.ToReal(y)+1/z3.ToReal(z))
s.add(x>0)
s.add(n>0)
s.add(y>0)
s.add(z>0)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[n = 4, x = 3, z = 3, y = 3]
```

again satisfying your constraints.

Comment: Thank you. Your second solution is what I needed.